# Watir WebDriver in conjunction with Java

Tags: java, watir-webdriver

Is it possible to use [Watir WebDriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/) in conjunction with Java? I have to execute some Java methods for dealing with data in DB in order to simulate different situations and test website UI using watir-webdriver.

I've read about JRuby, but could not find anything about whether it works with Watir WebDriver.

Please share your experience!

Comment: Welcome to SQA, mihijs.  I do not have any experience with Watir, but a Google search turned up [Watij][http://watij.com/].  Selenium/Webdriver has a Java API too.

Comment: "Watir WebDriver in conjunction with Java" == Watij

Comment: This would be a much better question with more context: what has been tried, what resource gaps or functionality gaps are missing, and tie-in to the actual business problem that's occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching if Watir works on JRuby, you could have just tried it, like I did:

```
$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.1 (1.9.3p327) 2012-12-03 30a153b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909 [darwin-x86_64]

$ gem install watir
...
Successfully installed watir-4.0.2

$ irb

> require "watir"
=> true

> browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x4fcd5906 url="about:blank" title="">

> browser.goto "google.com"
=> "http://www.google.hr/"
```

In case it is not clear, Watir works just fine on JRuby.

Comment: The question was whether it works with Java, not JRuby. The  approach itself is fine, though: "just try it!"